# The best approach for processing a large data on php

Tags: php, big-data

I am searching for the best approach for process a large amount data using PHP.

I want to create a xml file from a database, when I execute my code the system will stop with a "PHP timeout" error, I just adjusted php timeout value (not a valid solution).

Now I try to implement it with AJAX, is there any better way to do it easily?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running some sort of processing that will unavoidably take a long time then instead of doing it synchronously within the user's request it is usually better to do the processing asynchronously.

The user request would add the processing request to a job queue, then return immediately with a message that it will be processed shortly. You then have a background process which processes the data then informs the user (i.e. via an email or UI pop-up) that processing has completed, at which point they can then choose to view the results.

Comment: Hi,  Yes,  Job queue is a best option. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem the sheer *volume* of data or that it takes a long time to assemble it?

If it's the former (*too much* data) then ask yourself why you need to process so much all in one go.  If there's a User on the receiving end of [all] this data, you can pretty much guarantee that they *will not* want to read it all.

If if's the latter (taking *too long*) then you need to *tune* the SQL queries that make it up.